# Error en una variable input de tipo Scanner.nextLine()

Tags: java, scanner

En la parte del código donde inicia el ciclo `for`, la variable `nota_materias` no genera una entrada de texto en la consola sino que sigue derecho y guarda un cadena vacía.

¿Esto a que se debe?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de materias que cursó el semestre pasado");
byte num_materias = sc.nextByte(); //dato con tamaño de 8 bits perfecto para numeros pequeños
double suma = 0; // dato con tamaño 64 bits que incluye decimales

for (int i = 1; i <= num_materias; i++) { //dato con tamaño de 32 bits

    System.out.println("Ingrese la nota final de la materia " + i + "\ndigite los numeros decimales con \".\"");
    String nota_materias = sc.nextLine(); //dato tipo cadena
    suma += Double.parseDouble(nota_materias); //casteo de string a double
}

float promedio = (float) suma / num_materias; //casteo de double a float
System.out.println("Su promedio es: " + promedio);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eso pasa cuando utilizas el objeto Scanner para un tipo de dato y después querer utilizarlo para otro tipo de dato distinto. El buffer de entrado queda con residuo y de ahí el fallo.

Una solución que puedes implementar es instanciar de nuevo el objeto `Scanner` dentro del ciclo for:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num_materias; i++) { // dato con tamaño de 32 bits
        
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);//<---Aqui
    System.out.println("Ingrese la nota final de la materia " + i + "\ndigite los numeros decimales con \".\"");
```

De esta forma nos aseguramos de tener libre el buffer de entrada.

**Ejemplo completo:**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de materias que cursó el semestre pasado");
byte num_materias = sc.nextByte(); // dato con tamaño de 8 bits perfecto para numeros pequeños
double suma = 0; // dato con tamaño 64 bits que incluye decimales

for (int i = 1; i <= num_materias; i++) { // dato con tamaño de 32 bits
        
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Ingrese la nota final de la materia " + i + "\ndigite los numeros decimales con \".\"");
    String nota_materias = sc.nextLine(); // dato tipo cadena
    suma += Double.parseDouble(nota_materias); // casteo de string a double
}

float promedio = (float) suma / num_materias; // casteo de double a float
System.out.println("Su promedio es: " + promedio);
```

**Output:**

```
Ingrese el numero de materias que cursó el semestre pasado
4
Ingrese la nota final de la materia 1
digite los numeros decimales con "."
2.2
Ingrese la nota final de la materia 2
digite los numeros decimales con "."
3.3
Ingrese la nota final de la materia 3
digite los numeros decimales con "."
4.4
Ingrese la nota final de la materia 4
digite los numeros decimales con "."
8.8
Su promedio es: 4.675
```

Comment: Gracias, me ha funcionado.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes con `sc.nextLine()` es que tienes que entender como trabaja y como se combina con otras entradas de datos, lo que sucede con métodos como `sc.nextInt()`, `sc.nextByte();` y así con la mayoría de capturas de datos es que no consumen el salto de línea `\n` y al ejecutar `sc.nextLine()` consume ese salto de línea pendiente y por eso recibes vacío "" y no se detiene la ejecución.

Las soluciones a esto son:

1. Utilizar `sc.nextLine()` después de utilizar `sc.nextByte();` para descartar el salto de línea.
2. Para tú uso puedes utilizar `sc.next()` que obtiene un String, la diferencia es que `nextLine()` reconoce los espacios y `next()` captura los `String` que encuentre separado por espacios.

Aplicación Solución 1

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de materias que cursó el semestre pasado");
byte num_materias = sc.nextByte(); //dato con tamaño de 8 bits perfecto para numeros pequeños
sc.nextLine(); //consumo del salto de línea.
double suma = 0; // dato con tamaño 64 bits que incluye decimales

for (int i = 1; i <= num_materias; i++) { //dato con tamaño de 32 bits

    System.out.println("Ingrese la nota final de la materia " + i + "\ndigite los numeros decimales con \".\"");
    String nota_materias = sc.nextLine(); //dato tipo cadena
    suma += Double.parseDouble(nota_materias); //casteo de string a double
}

float promedio = (float) suma / num_materias; //casteo de double a float
System.out.println("Su promedio es: " + promedio);
```

Aplicación Solución 2

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Ingrese el numero de materias que cursó el semestre pasado");
byte num_materias = sc.nextByte(); //dato con tamaño de 8 bits perfecto para numeros pequeños

double suma = 0; // dato con tamaño 64 bits que incluye decimales

for (int i = 1; i <= num_materias; i++) { //dato con tamaño de 32 bits

    System.out.println("Ingrese la nota final de la materia " + i + "\ndigite los numeros decimales con \".\"");
    String nota_materias = sc.next(); //dato tipo cadena
    suma += Double.parseDouble(nota_materias); //casteo de string a double
}

float promedio = (float) suma / num_materias; //casteo de double a float
System.out.println("Su promedio es: " + promedio);
```

La diferencias es que si ingresas por ejemplo 2 materias y en `nota_materias`  escribes `7.5 10` con `nextLine()` capturas un `String` con valor `7.5 10` y recibirías un erro de conversión, pero con `next()` en la primera iteración captura `7.5`  y en la segunda no se detendría para ingresar un dato porque captura `10` que estaba pendiente en el `String` que se ingreso.